# Como fazer uma query depender do resultado da outra?

Tags: mysql

Considere a seguinte tabela:

```
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
| ID | fk_resource_id | fk_language_id | value  |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
| 1  | 1              | 1              | Entrar |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
| 2  | 1              | 2              | Login  |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
```

É necessário fazer um `select` com filtro através das colunas `value` e `fk_language_id`:

```
... WHERE value LIKE '%Ent%'
```

O resultado da query acima será:

```
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
| ID | fk_resource_id | fk_language_id | value  |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
| 1  | 1              | 1              | Entrar |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
```

Repare que existe a coluna `fk_resource_id`. Preciso que seja devolvido todos os registos que possuem o campo `fk_resource_id` com base no resultado da primeira query.

O resultado seria o seguinte:

```
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
| ID | fk_resource_id | fk_language_id | value  |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
| 1  | 1              | 1              | Entrar |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
| 2  | 1              | 2              | Login  |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------+
```

Eu sei que é o mesmo resultado da tabela inicial, mas há 2 pontos a considerar:

1. A tabela original possui muito mais registros e apenas utilizei 2 como exemplo.
2. Não posso passar para a primeira query o `fk_resource_id`, uma vez que a procura é pelos registros que possuem uma determinada string na coluna `value`.

**Update**: eu não preciso de juntar 2 tabelas. É preciso filtrar a tabela pelo campo `value` e com base no resultado da query obter todos os registos que possuem o mesmo `fk_resource_id` resultante da primeira query. Aqui temos penas 1 tabela e o `INNER JOIN` junta tudo em uma única row, o que preciso é de novas rows, tal como o exemplo acima.

Comment: A cláusula `in` não resolveria? Por exemplo: `select * from Tabela where fk_resource_id in (select fk_resource_id from Tabela where value LIKE '%Ent%')`?

Comment: ou a cláusula Exists... coloca no SQLFiddle que ajuda na hora de exemplificar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pesquisa deve ser realizada da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
    T1.CAMPO1, T1.CAMPO2, T1.CAMPO3
FROM
    TABELA T1
WHERE
    T1.CAMPO2 IN (SELECT T2.CAMPO2 FROM TABELA T2 WHERE T2.CAMPO3 LIKE '%Ent%')
```

Comment: Seu código pode gerar erro, uma vez que você usou `=` mas a subquery pode retornar mais de um registro, por causa do `like`.
O mais recomendado seria usar o `in` como eu havia comentado

Comment: Verdade, vou modificar a resposta.

Comment: É interessante explicar o porquê da estrutura utilizada ensinando assim "como pescar" e não apenas "dando o peixe"

Comment: É isso mesmo. Obrigado!